# How to retrieve the Email from Twitter and Google

Tags: django, twitter, google-oauth, django-allauth

i am using django-allauth with these settings:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'}
    },
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'pt_BR',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False
    }
}
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

Then when I made the login through Twitter or Google the Email is not filled in the User. But when I use another providers like Github or Facebook that users have the proper email.
Thanks in advance o/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  Twitter do not provide users' email addresses.

Source - https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5232